# Distorted and Choppy Audio

Tags: 12.04, sound, alsa

After installing 12.04 Precise on my PC, I have encountered some problems with audio output which did no occur when using Lucid.

The sound is choppy and distorted in the lower tones. As I have no experience in setting/testing and doing anything with Audio Devices, I need help even to diagnose the problem.

#### Update

```
$ sudo lshw -c multimedia

  *-multimedia  

       description: Audio device
       product: Radeon X1200 Series Audio Controller
       vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
       physical id: 5.2
       bus info: pci@0000:01:05.2
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
       resources: irq:19 memory:fdafc000-fdafffff
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
       vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
       physical id: 14.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
       resources: irq:16 memory:fe024000-fe027fff
```

#### Update 2

It has something to do with the volume. If the audio is quiet it is not choppy, if the sound is loud then it begins to be choppy.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "low range"? Doesn't the choppiness and distortion affect all audio?

Comment: The sound is choppy in general, and distorted for low range tones only. For me it seems like some buffering problem, or something similar.

Comment: Please update question with pastebin of `sudo lshw -c multimedia`.

Comment: I have this same problem... bassy sounds cause chopping/stuttering of playback in videos/audio. turning the volume down low reduces the choppiness. I can't listen to mp3 or watch vlc without sound freaking out. (snd_hda_intel driver for 6/C200 series Intel)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Misery, I seem to have found a solution on my system using the same driver (different audio device though)

1. Open Terminal: `gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
2. Add the following line:

   ```
   options snd-hda-intel model=generic
   ```
3. Restart System

My audio seems to be working fine now. Full volume, flash content, videos, audio files.
Let us know if it helps.

---

Credit goes to [Adityeah](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11935115&postcount=7)

Comment: it did the thing :]

Comment: This has not helped me get sound working correctly in [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/browse/linux/). (For future Googlers)

Comment: @earthmeLon This solution is for a problem that is system-wide. Not limited to one application. Sorry.

Comment: hey this did not worked for me ? i have intel i5 2nd generation Dell with IDT speakers

Comment: I'll have to test this.

Answer (score 5):

A possible solution is disabling "auto-mute" in alsamixer. It is used when the "switch-to-headphone-and-back-again" bug occurs (in high volumes mainly).

First, open your terminal, or press:

```
CTRL + ALT + T
```

Then, type and hit "enter":

```
$ alsamixer
```

This screen will show up:

[image: Alsa mixer screen in terminal]

Use the right arrow until you select "Auto-Mute"

Next, press the down arrow to set it do "Disable" (see the text above it).

Finally, press `Esc` to apply and exit

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

Install alsa-tools:

```
sudo apt install alsa-tools
```

Create and save a script in /usr/local/bin:

```
sudo vi /usr/local/bin/sound_fix.sh
```

Inside the script, write this:

```
#!/bin/bash
hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 SET_COEF_INDEX 0x67
hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 SET_PROC_COEF 0x3000
```

Run the script as root in a terminal to immediately fix the problem.

[Give permission](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49757/how-do-i-execute-a-bash-script-that-requires-root-privileges) to run using:

```
sudo chmod 700 [path_to_script_folder]/sound_fix.sh
```

Run the script using:

```
./[path_to_script_folder]/sound_fix.sh
```

To run the script on startup, use cron with the @reboot command:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and then add line in crontab:

```
@reboot [full_path_to_script_folder]/sound_fix.sh
```

To run script on resume from suspend, copy the script to

```
/lib/systemd/system-sleep
```

For more technical details regarding this fix, check [this](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195457) link.

Comment: perfect answer, working for 18.04

Comment: upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04, same problem, working for that too.

Answer (score 0):

For crackling noise in headphones especially on the left side..
write a bash script with the following lines

```
hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 SET_COEF_INDEX 0x67
hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 SET_PROC_COEF 0x3000
```

Don't forget to **execute** it **as root.**

And for systems which don't have hda-verb installed, you can install hda-verb from the respective package managers

Add the script to the startup scripts or there will be a neccesity to run the script everytime system boots up

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue. I tried all methods mentioned here. but didn't worked.

To solve the problem, I first watch this => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3Eyu4a1XD4 it didn't solve problem. but i kept all changes which are done according to video. then I enter following command,

```
$ sudo nano /etc/pulse/daemon.conf
```

it will open daemon.conf, then locate following line using arrow down/up.

> ;realtime-scheduling = yes

and remove " ; " and change it to,

> realtime-scheduling = no

then save it (press Ctrl+o then enter)(quit => Ctrl+x). finally, run following command **or** restart computer.

```
$ systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service
```

it was done job for me. Good luck. :)