# Sound became distorted

Tags: 12.04, sound

Good morning.

Today I was playing with sunvox and (probably after that) sound became quite or very distorted in many applications.

Thanks.

**add:**

If necessarily:

```
ben@pav:~$ sudo alsa reload
[sudo] password for ben: 
/sbin/alsa: Warning: Processes using sound devices: 2175(pulseaudio). 
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hrtimer snd-hda-codec-conexant snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-page-alloc snd-seq-midi snd-rawmidi snd-seq-midi-event snd-seq snd-timer snd-seq-device (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hrtimer snd-hda-codec-conexant snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-page-alloc snd-seq snd-timer snd-seq-device).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hrtimer snd-hda-codec-conexant snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-page-alloc snd-seq-midi snd-rawmidi snd-seq-midi-event snd-seq snd-timer snd-seq-device.
```

Sound was moved to the medium level in alsamixer. After killing pulseaudio I got no sound at all.

Some additional info:

```
ben@pav:~$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
ben@pav:~$ uname -r
3.2.0-23-generic
ben@pav:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xf2480000 irq 21
ben@pav:~$ aplay -l
**** Список PLAYBACK устройств ****
карта 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], устройство 0: CONEXANT Analog [CONEXANT Analog]
  Подустройства: 1/1
  Подустройство №0: subdevice #0
карта 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], устройство 1: Conexant Digital [Conexant Digital]
  Подустройства: 1/1
  Подустройство №0: subdevice #0
ben@pav:~$ aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Noise.wav
Воспроизведение WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Noise.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Частота 48000 Гц, Моно
ben@pav:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 audio 
00:07.0 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP65 High Definition Audio [10de:044a] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:30cf]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

Doing

```
sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio

sudo apt-get install alsa-utils gstreamer0.10-x
```

gave nothing.In `gstreamer-properties` I can see **no** output devices there and in `sound` menu element.

Comment: [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/138858/28757) makes nothing too.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, do you use **VLC**?
VLC comes with its own codecs and might conflict with others.
Try uninstalling VLC and retry.