# Choppy Audio on Realtek ALC888S

Tags: 12.04, sound, realtek

The onboard Realtek ALC888S is giving out choppy audio
Oddly, speech comes out fine but is at a low volume

Alsamixer detects it  as being `Realtek ALC1200` instead of `Realtek ALC888S`

[image]

and lspci:

```
amith@amith-desktop:~$ lspci|grep Audio
00:09.0 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation MCP73 High Definition Audio (rev a1)
```

The motherboard is a `HP NAPA GL8 G31` with a Core 2 Duo

Comment: check out this link..it worked for an intel card..http://askubuntu.com/questions/138266/distorted-choppy-audio-in-precise?rq=1

Comment: @Mukund Done that. No change :/