# Ubuntu 12.10 crackling and popping sound

Tags: 12.10, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hda-intel

I've an Asus Z92V, I am running Ubuntu 12.10 and since I installed Ubuntu on this notebook the audio keep crackling and popping continuously.
Moreover the volume bar on gnome-shell panel keep jumping from low volume to high volume continuously.
This is indifferently through speakers and headphones...it's an unbearable and annoying problem!!! 
Since it's a common problem of Intel-HDA-audio I've found a lot of solutions and hints around web, but nothing has solved my problem...

This is the output from `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"`:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Asus A6VC
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 41
Memory at febfc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
```

I tried to mute / unmute all mixer channels (via alsamixer), but it didn't change anything.

Please help me, guys...
Thanks

P.S. output from `sudo lshw -c multimedia`:

```
  *-multimedia            
   description: Audio device
   product: 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) High Definition Audio Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1b
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
   version: 04
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
   resources: irq:41 memory:febfc000-febfffff
```

Comment: Maybe this helps http://askubuntu.com/questions/138266/distorted-choppy-audio-in-precise

Comment: Thank you Misery, I've added that line in my alsa-base.conf and now sound from speakers is working fine!!!
But sadly, now headphones audio is mute, why???

Comment: Did you connect headphones to the same plug as speakers? I mean: disconnected speakers and connected headphones in the same place?

Comment: No, I use internal speakers (it's a notebook)...anyway yes, I connected headphones in the right input...

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the model=generic...I think that model doesn't allow me to use headphones. I've tried a lot of other models, like described here: (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto), but none of them worked :-( :-(
However thanks a lot Misery, at least now audio from speakers works fine!!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: Hi Balez! Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please add your solution as an answer and accept it. Answering your own questions is highly encouraged here to document the solution for others.

Comment: dupe [Distorted choppy audio in Precise](http://askubuntu.com/q/138266)

Comment: Hi @Balez , I see you're new to AskUbuntu. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older AskUbuntu questions which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution is disabling "auto-mute" in alsamixer. It is used when the "switch-to-headphone-and-back-again" bug occurs (in high volumes mainly).

First, open your terminal, or press:

```
CTRL + ALT + T
```

Then, type and hit "enter":

```
$ alsamixer
```

This screen will show up:

[image: Alsa mixer screen in terminal]

Use the right arrow until you select "Auto-Mute"

Then, press the down arrow to set it do "Disable" (see the text above it).

That's it.