# Very choppy sound Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit on Intel® Core™ i5-2500K CPU @ 3.30GHz × 4 PC.

When I go to system settings and click on sound, the screen keeps flashing between Analog Output and Headphones in the Play sound through section of the Output tab. The screen doesn't stay fixed, and I cant click on any of the buttons.

When I try to play music the sound is extremely choppy. In terminal I opened alsamixer, and the Surround, Center LFE and Side bars keep alternating between 0 and 100 (regardless of if my Logitech X-540 5.1 surround sound speakers are plugged in or not).

I know the speakers work fine because I have windows 7 installed on the same PC and it worked immediately without any configuration.

The ALSA Information Script from my PC can be found here:
http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=00d9028d1118a30e3fadc9bc458ca8d65b3a9f2c

I have tried uninstalling and reintalling alsa-base and pulse audio but that is not working. I also tried several suggestions including:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

if anyone has the same problem as I did, a combination of the following two solutions worked for me: 1)https://askubuntu.com/a/138858/230309  then 2)https://askubuntu.com/a/386145/230309