# Why are .mp3 audio files Popping & Crackling ?

Tags: sound, 14.04

When I try to play an .mp3 file I get continuous popping & crackling. If I play a video with audio, all works fine. I also have this problem playing You tube videos online. Is this a known issue and is there a fix ?

Here is the sound card I have :

```
*-multimedia            
   description: Audio device
   product: NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1b
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
   resources: irq:45 memory:f9000000-f9003fff
```

Thanks

**Edit:** found the solution

A possible solution is disabling "auto-mute" in alsamixer. It is used when the "switch-to-headphone-and-back-again" bug occurs (in high volumes mainly).

- First, open your terminal, or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
- Then, type the command below and hit `Enter`:

  alsamixer

You will get something like this:

[image]

- Now press the respective Arrow key( `->` or `<-` ) till you find auto mute option and disable it.

Crackling will now disappear.

Comment: Welcome to Ask ubuntu! You must probably post the 'Edit' section as an answer below and accept it. To do this you may just cut the Edit section and paste it as an answer below in the box provided for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 12.10 crackling and popping sound](http://askubuntu.com/questions/276769/ubuntu-12-10-crackling-and-popping-sound)