# Choppy Sound when using Dash - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sound

When I am listening to music or watching youtube, the sounds become distorted at the moment I open the Unity Dash to search for something.  Using headphones instead of the built-in speakers does not help.

I have tried the solutions here:

[Distorted and Choppy Audio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138266/distorted-choppy-audio-in-precise)

http://www.ejoom.com/blog/117-skype-linux-ubuntu-sound-choppy-distorted-crackling-scratchy

But they don't work for me.  Any help?

My laptop is a Lenovo Thinkpad T60