# Ubuntu 14.04 Sound Glitch

Tags: sound, 14.04

checked the forums and couldn’t find a topic related to my current problem.
Sometimes under heavy sound demand, I.e. playing a game or watching a video my sound has this well, I don’t really know how to describe it but it sounds like a hard lag.
But the main sound comes through while the background has this weird echoed,and or lagged um thunder sound, that’s really the best way I can describe.
It I always have my headphones in would it be a problem with them or maybe my audio drivers I just have a basic Realtek one built into my mother board.

Thanks for reading again

Comment: Could you provide us with the output of `sudo lshw`?

Comment: "PCI (sysfs)", is all that comes up when i sudo lshw

Comment: It should show a result after a few seconds. Try waiting for it to complete.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Distorted choppy audio in Precise](http://askubuntu.com/questions/138266/distorted-choppy-audio-in-precise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the generic fix for Realtek audio that usually fixes a number of issues. Grab yourself a terminal and enter the following line -

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Add this on a new line at the end of the configuration file -

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

Save and restart your computer.

If that doesn't work, repeat the same but change `model=generic` to `model=auto`