# Ubuntu 17.04 Sound Glitch

Tags: sound, 17.04

Sometimes the audio glitches (repeat), for example if I would speak with someone on Discord I will hear "hey what's up what's up" when the person only says "hey what's up".
I don't have this problem on Windows or any other linux distros(I used this build with elementary os & deepin os before). I also tried reinstalling Ubuntu but the problem still persists.

I tried this but didn't helped: [Ubuntu 14.04 Sound Glitch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464877/ubuntu-14-04-sound-glitch)