# Distorted sound (like voice removal) on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

After a while (after rebooting my computer), my sound output gets distorted. When listening to music containing voice, it sounds like voice is removed.

I tried:

1/

```
sudo alsa force-reload
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio --start
```

2/ Modifying my /etc/pulse/daemon.conf as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1108826/1005380).

3/ Setting `options snd-hda-intel model=generic` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/464892/1005380).

without any success.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: I have the same problems too, with two PCs, when I am watching videos on Youtube. I solve the problem by closing the navigator then reopen it again..

Comment: @singrium It is not working for me.