# Sound problems in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, rhythmbox, music

I am having problems using my audio ports in Ubuntu 14.04. I didnt notice this before, because I use wireless speakers and they use a USB port. But today I tried to use my headphones and I heard horrible static and some kind of lag. I was listening to music on youtube at the time and I also saw that the video/music began to play at a faster rate. This was again confirmed when I listened to music on Rythmbox and the same thing was happening.

Then I tried to listen to music via my monitor that is connected to my computer with a HDMI-cabel. The static was there too, making the music hard to recognize... needless to say, it was unlistenable.. unless you like some really weird and crazy  kind of music remixes. ;)

Otherwise the sound works perfectly via USB.

What can I do to fix this?

output of  `sudo lshw -C multimedia` follows

`*-multimedia description: Audio device product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] physical id: 0.1 bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1 version: 00 width: 64 bits clock: 33MHz capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0 resources: irq:46 memory:f7e60000-f7e63fff`

`*-multimedia description: Audio device product: Intel Corporation vendor: Intel Corporation physical id: 1b bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0 version: 00 width: 64 bits clock: 33MHz capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0 resources: irq:45 memory:f7f10000-f7f13fff`

Best regards! :)

Comment: Please provide the output of `sudo lshw -C multimedia` **without** your USB wireless speakers attached. This will help us help you. Thank you.

Comment: Some ALSA drivers are broken in pulse audio: You may find this interesting: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Backends/ALSA/BrokenDrivers/

Answer (score 0):

I believe this to be a bug in the driver, there appears to be a workaround which may work for you:

You have to modify the following line in /etc/pulse/default.pa

load-module module-udev-detect

with :

load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0

sources:

munbi at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/751265/comments/23

http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Backends/ALSA/BrokenDrivers/

If this approach doesn't work for you, look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) and [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems) for further instruction.

You can also try this: [Distorted and Choppy Audio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138266/distorted-choppy-audio-in-precise)

Comment: I have already tried to do this and it didnt work. What can I try next? Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Edited answer..

Comment: The main problem seems to be that the music is playing at a faster rate than it should. For example in 1 second, 3 seconds of music are played. For some strange reason this static sound went away for some time when I started watched youtube and set the speed of the video from normal to 2x and then to 0.5. The music could be heard correctly (no static sound or distorsions). Sadly this issue still persists in music players and even in youtube IF  for example I scroll down and read the comments... so if I lose sight of the video, the sound starts to play faster even if the speed is set to normal.

Comment: This is a different question from the static question. Please search for answers applying to audio plays too fast and if you can't find an existing solution open a new question using the button in the upper right hand corner. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've used a couple of days ago bluetooth headset and had a similar issue. I went to the pavucontrol and in the configuration tab where it was possible to switch to a mode with better quality (but sacrifice the microphone). After that, everything was perfect.