# Ubuntu 14.04 Pulseaudio in HDMI sound crackling

Tags: 14.04, ati, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I've recently change my PC OS from MS to Ubuntu.

Ubuntu 14.04 can correctly find my HDMI audio but with terrible echo and crackling sound.

I fix the echo issue by following the guide here: [Sound problems in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492467/sound-problems-in-ubuntu-14-04), and [Static and crackling in my HDMI audio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405071/static-and-crackling-in-my-hdmi-audio). But the crackling sound still exist. I tried updating the video card driver directly from AMD website, didn't help either.

I also try to change the default sampling frequency in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` to 44100 or 48000, both won't work.

I'm using video card MSI ATI R7 260x. How can I fix it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1321421

Cause my PC comes with an Intel Z97/H97 chipset, the solution to solve this problem is:

1. `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
2. Add `options snd-hda-intel vid=8086 pid=8ca0 snoop=0` at the end of the file.
3. Restart PC

Comment: Solved my radeon 290x hdmi audio noise/crackes on Ubuntu 14.04, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This one helped me: [Static and crackling in my HDMI audio?]: [Static and crackling in my HDMI audio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405071/static-and-crackling-in-my-hdmi-audio)

edit

```
/etc/pulse/default.pa
```

look for

```
load-module module-udev-detect
```

add tsched=0

```
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
```

reboot

Comment: worked for me without a full reboot just a reload of the alsa service with `sudo alsa force-reload`

Answer (score 0):

This was taken on Ubuntu website and solved it for me

**HDMI Audio**

The open-source radeon driver supports HDMI audio on Radeon HD 6000-series and earlier chips. On Trusty/14.04 and newer, HDMI audio should work automatically.

On release older than Trusty/14.04, users will need to to enable HDMI audio manually by passing the radeon.audio=1 kernel parameter. It can be done with the following command:

```
echo "options radeon audio=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/radeon.conf
```

Ubuntu Precise/12.04 users should also note that they may need a newer kernel (>= 3.5.x) to enable HDMI audio on later cards