# Choppy and Distorted Audio

Tags: sound, lubuntu, 16.04, pulseaudio, alsa

I have exactly the same problem as explained in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138266/distorted-and-choppy-audio), however the question is very old and the provided answers doesn't work so I decided to ask the question again:

Sound from audio,video and in generalany of sound is choppy. I can hear some part but then immediatly it mutes.

outout of `sudo lshw -c multimedia`

```
  *-multimedia            
       description: Audio device
       product: System Controller Hub (SCH Poulsbo) HD Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1b
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:22 memory:b0050000-b0053fff
  *-usb
       description: Video
       product: WebCam
       vendor: Sonix Technology Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 4
       bus info: usb@1:4
       version: 1.00
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=98mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

I use Lubuntu 16 on acer aspire one.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was to edit `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/pulse/daemon.conf
```

Find the line

```
; resample-method =
```

uncomment (remove the `;`) and change to

```
resample-method = src-sinc-best-quality
```

If the line is not there at all, then add it.

Reboot for changes to take effect.

Comment: no, it didnt solve the problem