# Distorted audio over headphones in Ubuntu 17.04 dual booted with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, sound, windows-10, hp, 17.04

#### Overview

I have Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 installed along side Windows 10 on my HP Pavilion 15 AU113TX laptop. Sometimes when I switch to Ubuntu from Windows, I get distorted audio from left earphone while listening to anything.

This issue is intermittent as sometimes audio comes out just fine right after I booted to Ubuntu, however it starts causing problems again if I put Ubuntu to sleep and wake it up after couple of hours. On Windows 10, however, audio works perfectly even after reboots from Ubuntu or after waking up from sleep.

#### Affected Ubuntu Version

While I'm tagging 17.04 with the question, this issue occurred Ubuntu 16.10 as well, I haven't tried 16.04 though, since it originally shipped with Kernel 4.4 which doesn't have very good support for Kaby Lake chipset (which my laptop has).

#### Tried Solutions

I did go through Ubuntu's [Audio Troubleshoot Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) but it didn't fix my problem. There are 3 related questions;

1. [Distorted and Choppy Audio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138266/distorted-and-choppy-audio)
2. [Choppy and Distorted Audio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776748/choppy-and-distorted-audio)
3. [How can I fix choppy audio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707171/how-can-i-fix-choppy-audio)

Unfortunately, none of those questions mention dual boot scenario and neither the solution they propose fix the problem.

#### Diagnostic Information

Output for command `sudo lshw -c multimedia`

```
    *-usb:1                   
           description: Video
           product: HP Wide Vision HD
           vendor: DFKAR019I333QL
           physical id: 3
           bus info: usb@1:3
           version: 0.04
           capabilities: usb-2.00
           configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
    *-multimedia
           description: Audio device
           product: Intel Corporation
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 1f.3
           bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
           version: 21
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
           configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
           resources: irq:135 memory:b4328000-b432bfff memory:b4310000-b431ffff
```

Any help in fixing this would be appreciated, also let me know if I need to put output for any more commands. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there's a bug with HP audio driver which causes this problem. I could successfully fix it with following solution. Note that this solution is applicable only if your audio device is **Realtek ALC295**.

> Install alsa-tools if not installed:
>
> `sudo apt install alsa-tools`
>
> Create and save a script in /usr/local/bin:
>
> `#!/bin/bash
>    hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 SET_COEF_INDEX 0x67
>    hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 SET_PROC_COEF 0x3000`
>
> Run the script as root in a terminal to immediately fix the problem.
>
> To run the script on startup, use cron with the `@reboot` command:
>
> `sudo crontab -e`
>
> and then add line in crontab:
>
> `@reboot [full path to script]`
>
> To run script on resume from suspend, copy the script to `/lib/systemd/system-sleep`

source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1648183/comments/17

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Give this a shot it ended up working for me

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```