# Cannot hear properly from earphones

Tags: sound

I am using Ubuntu 19.04 GNOME 3.32.1. When I put my earphones in the headphone jack, I cannot listen to any audio properly and everything is kind of muffled and unclear. I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910439/distorted-audio-over-headphones-in-ubuntu-17-04-dual-booted-with-windows-10) and nothing seems to work so far.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please issue the command `mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/old_pulse`. **Reboot** your system. Now, please check your audio. If it fails, then try this command `sudo alsa force-reload`. **Reboot** your system. Now again check for audio. Also please post the output of `pulseaudio` command.

Comment: I am glad that your problem was solved! Good Luck!!